# row header in mdx queries

Tags: header, row, ssas, mdx

Can anyone explain how to add row headers to the following query?  I'm sure there is a way, surprised that the column headers appear but the row headers are null.

By row headers I mean the top of the returned data, in gray that actually shows the name of the row returned.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3sJ3.png)

Answer (score 2):

That is `SSMS` and the way it displays the data.

In `MDX Studio` we get this:

[image]

...but SSMS and MDXStudio are not front end clients so this is just the way they have been designed.

If you are using say Excel as a front-end then you will maybe use a pivot-table to display the data - column headers will be the same as any other pivot table

If you are using SSRS then you can name the columns in your Datasets.

Other front-end clients will deal with this differently.